# Nilpotent stalks deducing nilpotent ideal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Question:Suppose $X$ is a Noetherian scheme, $ I$ is a sheaf of ideals(not necessarily quasi-coherent!) If we know all stalks of $I$ are nilpotent(i.e. for any $P\in X$ there exists a $n_P$ such that $I_P^{n_P}=0$). How to deduce there is a $n$ such that $I_P^n=0$ for any $P$?

I want to show sets $U_m:=\{P\in X:I_P^m=0\}$ are open, hence form an ascending chain, then by noetherian property we will find the biggest $n$. But I have no idea how to show $U_m$ are open since I don't have the quasi-coherent condition.

Comment: Hint: can you embed $I$ in a bigger nilpotent ideal, which is quasi-coherent?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268138/if-a-function-vanishes-at-all-points-of-a-quasicompact-scheme-then-some-power-o/)

Comment: @Mindlack Ah, just embed it in the nilradical of the scheme... Thanks.